# parent child relationship vs linking table

Tags: database-design

I have a project management database structure which is modeled on a parent/child structure.

```
item (id,parentId)
```

However, I am told that I should be using a linking table instead.

```
item(id)

linkingtable(parentId,childId)
```

Currently, there is no requirement that the items can be linked many to many, so I do not see any benefit.

Am I missing anything?

I am a c# programmer, not a database designer, so want to make sure of what I am doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO if there is a slightest possibility of making the relation `ManyToMany` in future than you should go for association or intermediate table.

But if you are sure that this relation is pure `ManyToOne` then no need to create additional table.